# how to set the last textbox value using jquery?

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, local-storage

I have a text box.I want to get the last text value.I am using local storage to save the text value and get the text value.
Here is my code:

```
$(function() {

        var textbox = $("#text");
        textbox.change(function() {
            var value=$("#text").val();
            localStorage.setItem("textboxValue",value);
        });
        var checkValue = localStorage.getItem("textboxValue");
       textbox.append(checkValue);
    });
```

But i am not able to append the value in textbox.Please kindly guide me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
textbox.val(checkValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this to set the textbox value:

```
textbox.val(checkValue);
```

Source:
http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

$.append is for appending elements to the DOM, not manipulating DOM properties. As the others have said, you want to use textbox.val(checkValue).

textbox.val(checkValue) will replace the contents of the textbox with checkValue. If you truly want to append to the text that is already in the textbox use:

textbox.val(textbox.val() + checkValue)